# What do square brackets mean in pip install?

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management

I see more and more commands like this:

```
$ pip install "splinter[django]"
```

What do these square brackets do?

Comment: http://logan.tw/posts/2015/01/01/python-package-manager-pip/

Comment: Note that it *should* be `pip install "splinter[django]"`, to avoid any accidental shell expansion of the pattern.

Comment: Note that there is a proposal to expose the available extras from the pip cli: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4824

Comment: @Ry-♦ Documentation link updated to: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The syntax that you are using is:

```
pip install "project[extra]"
```

---

In your case, you are `installing` the `splinter` package which has the added support for `django`.

*An explanation from `@chepner`*:

• `pip install splinter django` would install two packages named `splinter` and `django`.

• `pip install splinter[django]`, on the other hand, installs a variant of the `splinter` package which contains *support* for `django`.

Note that it has nothing to do with the `django` package itself, but is just a string defined by the `splinter` package for a particular feature set that gets enabled. How the argument `django` is interpreted depends on the build system, but any setuptools-based build system (including most instances of `setup.py`) will likely just use them as a hook for [optional dependencies](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies).

Comment: Care to expand on your answer so future users can benefit? For example what does `extra` mean?

Comment: Ok, how is this different from `pip install splinter django`?

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan That command would install two packages named `splinter` and `django`. `splinter[django]`, on the other hand, installs a variant of the `splinter` package which contains support for `django`. Note that it has nothing to do with the `django` package itself, but is just a string defined by the `splinter` package for a particular feature set that gets enabled.

Comment: @chepner Cool, now add a proper answer so future users can benefit.

Comment: @chepner That explanation was much clearer than anything I could find elsewhere so I added it to the answer!

Comment: @chepner So this is just a naming convention, and the `splinter[django]` is an actual package name? Or is there more going on here?

Comment: `splinter` is still the package name; `pip` itself parses `splinter[django]` and recognizes it as a package name with an extra "argument" to help it install the correct files. How the argument `django` is interpreted is entirely up to the `setup.py` file (or some other config file? I don't actually know the details) used to define the package `splinter`.

Comment: @JoeIddon Your answer's first part still conflicts with the second part that's why I am not accepting it. First part insists that django package is installed, while second part contradicts it. Please fix your answer.

Comment: I believe the only thing the [extra] syntax does is specify additional from extras_requires that will be installed.  That is, `pip install splinter` will install fewer requirements than `pip install splinter[django]`.  The additional packages that are installed may indeed (and probably do) enable additional features of splinter to work, but it doesn't change anything about the splinter package itself.  It just tells pip about additional dependencies.

Comment: Strange, I searched splinter[django] on PyPI and the result shows:Index of Packages Matching 'splinterdjango'
There were no matches.

Comment: Never thought I'd have to use this 'till today, thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Very often, we should notice the quotes ``pip install "project[extra]"``. Without the quotes, it causes problems in some shells because ``[]`` is a special syntax for them.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. This does not install a "splinter[django]" package, but rather both splinter and Django projects. These are setuptools extras as explained in answers by @paul and prosti

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Look at [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/setup.py) package. It has an `elasticsearch[async]` flavor which contains the exact same code as when installing `elasticsearch`, but simply installs `aiohttp` in addition to make sure using the async classes works well. There is no separate `elasticsearch[async]` package

Comment: "Really, you are installing the package named: 'splinter[django]'." <- I don't think this is correct. I just ran `pip install splinter[django]`, and `pip freeze` doesn't show any package name called splinter[django] but rather the packages splinter and django separatedly.

Comment: Here is more correct solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60307740/9913319

Answer (score 136):

## Brackets `[optional]` in PIP signify optional dependencies

Just in case another developer comes along looking to implement this pattern in their own Python package deployment, here's further explanation of the `brackets []` in pip.

## For Example: Apache Airflow

To install `airflow` from **pip** we use this command:

```sh
pip install 'apache-airflow'
```

You can install *optional* components of airflow with:

```sh
pip install 'apache-airflow[aws]'
#      [optional] -----------^
```

When we **search** **pypi** for `apache-airflow` note that the optional packages do not show up:

```sh
pip search 'apache-airflow'

apache-airflow (1.10.9)                            - Programmatically author, schedule and monitor data pipelines
pylint-airflow (0.1.0a1)                           - A Pylint plugin to lint Apache Airflow code.
swe-airflow-tools (0.0.3)                          - Tools for Apache Airflow Application
airflow (0.6)                                      - Placeholder for the old Airflow package
...
```

## Implementation via `setup.py`

You can see how this was accomplished in the `setup.py` [script](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/setup.py)
On the left in [`setup.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/setup.py#L514) - `extras_require` is defined.
On the right are the correlated installation commands for these optional sub-packages.

[image: setup.py vs install]

Answer (score 32):

Maybe worthwhile to know that this optional package syntax admits multiple extras (separated by comma within the brackets) as in:

```
python -m pip install SomePackage[PDF,EPUB]  # multiple extras
```

As per the [pip manual](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples)

Comment: But could I query how many those “recommended” dependencies are available? And especially, are all of them independent and combinable/compatible with each other? Could I just install all of them, something like `pip install package[*] `?

Answer (score 31):

Pretty sure these are setuptools extras:

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies

> Sometimes a project has “recommended” dependencies, that are not required for all uses of the project. For example, a project might offer optional PDF output if ReportLab is installed, and reStructuredText support if docutils is installed. These optional features are called “extras” ...

Answer (score 14):

## TLDR

The square bracket contains the 'extra' option's information defined in setup.py that pip will use to install additional dependencies.

```
pip install "splinter[django]"
```

To be specific, the above line will install first the 'splinter' package, then install the extra dependencies the 'splinter' project requires with the 'django' option specified in a setup.py of 'splinter' project.

## Explanation

```
pip install "splinter[django]" 

pip install "splinter" "Django>=2.0.6" "lxml>=4.2.4" "cssselect"
```

As of splinter==0.16.0, with python==3.9.2, the above two commands are equivalent.

Both pip install will result in the following packages given a clean virtual enviroment.

[image]

The reason why the two pip install commands achieve same is because this is literally what has been run in the background based on the [setup.py](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/master/setup.py) of the splinter package
[image]

The '[django]' is the 'extra' option for the 'splinter' package. Pip will look into the setup.py of splinter package, and find what needs to be installed with the '[django]' option specified. In this case, it is these 3 packages: ["Django>=2.0.6", "lxml>=4.2.4", "cssselect"]

Comment: [Prefer text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @ggorlen Imho, in this particular case, the image is way more informative than the text would be.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins If you had a data limit, a visual impairment or a corporate firewall or you wanted to zoom the text or copy and paste something from the answer, or use the site with consistent dark mode and consistent fonts, you'd probably feel differently. I'm not sure what value the images are adding here. They're just screenshots of text. If every answer looked like this, the site would be nigh-unusable. Please read [the provided link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). It's the site standard.

Comment: @ggorlen--onLLMstrike I agree about the first image. Absolutely no reason to use an image here. As for the second one, it is a limitation of the markdown subset used by SO: markdown and HTML tags are ignored within code blocks. And in this particular case highlighting the most relevant part of the huge block of text is absolutely helpful while providing no context at, all as done in the other answers, makes it less evident for the reader. As for me, I've even used the ascii-art in my answers to alleviate the issue :) but here I'd vote for an image — with a shorter text version in the alt tag.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly the list from the `setup.py` file for the project in [question](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/master/setup.py#L30):

```
"django": ["Django>=1.7.11;python_version<'3.0'", "Django>=2.0.6;python_version>'3.3'", "lxml>=2.3.6", "cssselect", "six"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Except [`extras_require`](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/fe4b8205c28a104fa592366c85a4ca6f4b8035ad/setup.py#L56-L61) in setup.py, this extra dependences maybe specified in `[project.optional-dependencies]` of pyproject.toml too.

see https://github.com/reactive-python/reactpy/blob/403e5f24536808218c511ed0ee0438fd6e1b94c8/src/py/reactpy/pyproject.toml#L38-L65.