# How to make setuptools install a wheel containing multiple packages?

Tags: python, azure, setuptools

Suppose this wheel:

```
M Filemode      Length  Date         Time      File
- ----------  --------  -----------  --------  -------------------------------------------
  -rw-rw-r--      1358  26-Sep-2018  21:08:40  azure/common/__init__.py
  -rw-rw-r--       327  26-Sep-2018  21:08:40  azure/common/_version.py
  -rw-rw-r--      8737  26-Sep-2018  21:08:40  azure/common/client_factory.py
  -rw-rw-r--       755  26-Sep-2018  21:08:40  azure/common/cloud.py
  -rw-rw-r--      2479  26-Sep-2018  21:08:40  azure/common/credentials.py
  -rw-rw-r--       805  26-Sep-2018  21:08:40  azure/common/exceptions.py
  -rw-rw-r--      6079  26-Sep-2018  21:08:40  azure/profiles/__init__.py
  -rw-rw-r--      3943  26-Sep-2018  21:08:40  azure/profiles/multiapiclient.py
  -rw-rw-r--         6  26-Sep-2018  21:21:54  azure_common-1.1.16.dist-info/top_level.txt
  -rw-rw-r--       110  26-Sep-2018  21:21:54  azure_common-1.1.16.dist-info/WHEEL
  -rw-rw-r--      3805  26-Sep-2018  21:21:54  azure_common-1.1.16.dist-info/METADATA
  -rw-rw-r--       997  26-Sep-2018  21:21:54  azure_common-1.1.16.dist-info/RECORD
- ----------  --------  -----------  --------  -------------------------------------------
                 29401                         12 files
```

It has three different packages in it:

- azure.common
- azure.profiles
- azure_common

All great names, and great layout.  Also, a lot of greatness of mind that unmistakably went into engineering this miracle of modern software engineering.

This wheel is distributed by the name `azure-common`.  So, when you depend on in in `setup.py` like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['azure-common'],
    ...
)
```

You will only get `azure_common` package installed.  Maybe.  I don't really know, it seems so, but few times that I tried it seemed to only install `azure.common`, or maybe I eyeballed it...  It's really hard to follow all the manipulations setuptools does on a package.

Hence the question: how can I force `setuptools` into installing all packages found in this kind of wheel?  Also, the order is important because this garbage needs to be installed some of the times with other packages which also provide `azure.something` packages which may overwrite the stuff in `azure` directory.  So, Ideally, I'd also like to control in which order `install_requires` dependencies are processed.

---

This is where this started: [How to specify bracket dependencies in setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53582037/5691066)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like only few sub-directories like `azure.common` installed into your environment when you installed dependencies via `setup.py` with `install_requires=['azure-common']`. I tried to reproduce this issue, but failed that all files in this package has been installed.

Here is my steps on my local Windows machine as below, which you can refer to.

1. Create a directory `mkdir setuptmp`, and create a virtual environment `virtualenv setuptmp`, then to `cd setuptmp`.
2. Create a `setup.py` file with the content as below.\

   ```
   from setuptools import setup, find_packages  

   setup(
       name = "setuptmp",
       install_requires = ['azure-common']
   )
   ```
3. Activate the virtual environment via `Scripts\activate.bat`.
4. Run `python setup.py install` to install the dependency described in my `setup.py`.
5. Run `python` to open the REPL interpreter to test all packages as you said,

   ```
   (setuptmp) D:\projects\setuptmp>python
   Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import azure.common
   >>> import azure.profiles
   >>> azure.common.__file__
   'D:\\projects\\setuptmp\\lib\\site-packages\\azure_common-1.1.16-py3.7.egg\\azure\\common\\__init__.py'
   >>> azure.profiles.__file__
   'D:\\projects\\setuptmp\\lib\\site-packages\\azure_common-1.1.16-py3.7.egg\\azure\\profiles\\__init__.py'
   >>> import azure_common
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure_common'
   ```

Note: `azure_common` is not a module, just an egg info directory.

6. Check the packages installed in my environment via `cd Lib\site-packages`, `dir` and `tree azure_common-1.1.16-py3.7.egg /F` as below.

   ```
   (setuptmp) D:\projects\setuptmp\Lib\site-packages>dir
    Volume in drive D is Data
    Volume Serial Number is BA4B-64AA

    Directory of D:\projects\setuptmp\Lib\site-packages

   2018/12/26  14:48    <DIR>          .
   2018/12/26  14:48    <DIR>          ..
   2018/12/26  14:48    <DIR>          azure_common-1.1.16-py3.7.egg
   2018/12/26  14:48                61 easy-install.pth
   2018/12/26  14:46               126 easy_install.py
   2018/12/26  14:46    <DIR>          pip
   2018/12/26  14:46    <DIR>          pip-18.1.dist-info
   2018/12/26  14:46    <DIR>          pkg_resources
   2018/12/26  14:48               965 setuptmp-0.0.0-py3.7.egg
   2018/12/26  14:46    <DIR>          setuptools
   2018/12/26  14:46    <DIR>          setuptools-40.6.3.dist-info
   2018/12/26  14:46    <DIR>          wheel
   2018/12/26  14:46    <DIR>          wheel-0.32.3.dist-info
   2018/12/26  14:46    <DIR>          __pycache__
                  3 File(s)          1,152 bytes
                 11 Dir(s)  80,896,319,488 bytes free

   (setuptmp) D:\projects\setuptmp\Lib\site-packages>tree azure_common-1.1.16-py3.7.egg /F
   Folder PATH listing for volume Data
   Volume serial number is BA4B-64AA
   D:\PROJECTS\SETUPTMP\LIB\SITE-PACKAGES\AZURE_COMMON-1.1.16-PY3.7.EGG
   ├─azure
   │  ├─common
   │  │  │  client_factory.py
   │  │  │  cloud.py
   │  │  │  credentials.py
   │  │  │  exceptions.py
   │  │  │  _version.py
   │  │  │  __init__.py
   │  │  │
   │  │  └─__pycache__
   │  │          _version.cpython-37.pyc
   │  │          __init__.cpython-37.pyc
   │  │
   │  └─profiles
   │          multiapiclient.py
   │          __init__.py
   │
   └─EGG-INFO
           PKG-INFO
           RECORD
           requires.txt
           top_level.txt
           WHEEL
   ```
7. Compare the above with the file structure of `azure-common` package downloaded from the [link](https://pypi.org/project/azure-common/#files) of Pypi website. I decompressed `azure_common-1.1.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl` file using `7-Zip` into a temp directory and `tree` it.

   ```
   D:\tmp>tree azure_common-1.1.16-py2.py3-none-any /F
   Folder PATH listing for volume Data
   Volume serial number is BA4B-64AA
   D:\tmp\AZURE_COMMON-1.1.16-PY2.PY3-NONE-ANY
   ├─azure
   │  ├─common
   │  │      client_factory.py
   │  │      cloud.py
   │  │      credentials.py
   │  │      exceptions.py
   │  │      _version.py
   │  │      __init__.py
   │  │
   │  └─profiles
   │          multiapiclient.py
   │          __init__.py
   │
   └─azure_common-1.1.16.dist-info
           METADATA
           RECORD
           top_level.txt
           WHEEL
   ```

Then, you will find the file structure of step `6` & `7` is almost same.

Hope it helps. If you have any concern, please feel free to let me know.

---

I did the same above on Linux and got the same result. I saved the output of `tree lib/ > lib_[before|after].txt` of my Linux `setuptmp` before and after run `python setup.py install`, then to compare them using `diff lib_*.txt` as below.

```
(setuptmp) peter@peterpc:~/setuptmp$ diff lib*.txt
92a93,111
>     │   ├── azure_common-1.1.16-py3.6.egg
>     │   │   ├── EGG-INFO
>     │   │   │   ├── PKG-INFO
>     │   │   │   ├── RECORD
>     │   │   │   ├── WHEEL
>     │   │   │   ├── requires.txt
>     │   │   │   └── top_level.txt
>     │   │   └── azure
>     │   │       ├── common
>     │   │       │   ├── __init__.py
>     │   │       │   ├── _version.py
>     │   │       │   ├── client_factory.py
>     │   │       │   ├── cloud.py
>     │   │       │   ├── credentials.py
>     │   │       │   └── exceptions.py
>     │   │       └── profiles
>     │   │           ├── __init__.py
>     │   │           └── multiapiclient.py
>     │   ├── easy-install.pth
827a847
>     │   ├── setuptmp-0.0.0-py3.6.egg
1043c1063
< 118 directories, 922 files
---
> 123 directories, 937 files
```

Comment: Oh, come on... who cares if it works on Windows? You are installing a completely different package using completely different installer :/

Comment: @wvxvw Hi, I did the same on Linux and got the same. I don't understand what means about `a different package using different installer` as you said.

Comment: When you install on Windows, you get different packages (Wheels distinguish platforms, and you can stuff virtually unrelated things into packages for different platforms). Similarly, whatever `setuptools` does on Windows is not very relevant to what it does on Linux. Locating all sorts of directories on both platforms results in different and inconsistent results.  But, if it somehow worked for you, then what version of `setuptools` did you use? What Linux? What version of `azure-common` did you get installed?  Because, clearly, it doesn't install the said packages for me with any combo.