# UnknownExtra error when installing via setup.py but not via pip

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, ray

I use [`ray[rllib]`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) as a dependency for my Python package.
Installing it via `pip install ray[rllib]` works perfectly fine.
But listing `ray[rllib]` as dependency in my `setup.py` like this:

```py
requirements = [
    'ray[rllib]==1.1.0',
# ...
}
```

leads to an error when running `python setup.py develop`: `pkg_resources.UnknownExtra: ray 1.1.0 has no such extra feature 'rllib'`.

I found a few related questions, eg, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582037/how-to-specify-bracket-dependencies-in-setup-py/53582278), but they don't apply/solve my problem.
`ray` does define the extra `rllib` in [its `setup.py`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/setup.py).

Any idea how to solve this? I'm happy to contribute a patch/PR to ray.

Currently, my only workaround is first to manually install `ray[rllib]` via `pip` and then the remaining dependencies of my package with `python setup.py install`. But this isn't nice.

Comment: Did you eventually figure it out? -- Looks like I can not recreate the issue. The requirement notation seems correct. -- Wait, looks like I can recreate the issue after all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general recommendation nowadays (from *setuptools* maintainers themselves) is to stop using:

- `python setup.py install`
- `python setup.py develop`

and instead use the following:

- `python -m pip install .`
- `python -m pip install --editable .`

---

But to be honest, I am a bit surprised that things fail here. I do not know exactly what is going wrong here in *setuptools*, and why `python setup.py develop` fails here.

Comment: So `pip install --editable .` works for you? I'll also check it out and let you know.

Comment: Yes with pip it works for me. I was able to recreate the issue when using `python setup.py develop` but never when using `python -m pip install --editable .`.