# Why does pip skip bracket package in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip

I have a requirements.txt as follows

```
boxsdk
boxsdk[jwt]
```

If I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, then only `boxsdk` gets installed, and not `boxsdk[jwt]`

```
# cat requirements.txt 
boxsdk
boxsdk[jwt]
# pip -q install -r requirements.txt 
# python -c "import boxsdk.auth.jwt_auth"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boxsdk/auth/jwt_auth.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

But if I remove the first line so that only `boxsdk[jwt]` is listed in `requirements.txt`, it gets installed properly

```
# cat requirements.txt 
boxsdk[jwt]
# pip -q install -r requirements.txt 
# python -c "import boxsdk.auth.jwt_auth"
#
```

Full pip output can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/davidkazuhiro/989328734e128628dd53ccab741f3e45

Why is `boxsdk[jwt]` getting skipped in the former case?

Comment: don't forget the green tick if you find my answer useful 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `requirements.txt` is equivalent to the following command

```
pip install boxsdk boxsdk[jwt]
```

so my answer will be based on the above command.

According to [What do square brackets mean in pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46775346/5958455), `boxsdk[jwt]` specifies **a variant** of the `boxsdk` package.

Because you specified `boxsdk` in the first place, when going over `boxsdk[jwt]`, pip notices that `boxsdk` has already been specified in the command line (or one same `requirements.txt`), and silently ignores duplicated package specification.

On the other hand, this command successfully installed everything:

```
pip install boxsdk[jwt] boxsdk
```

So, you should put the one with `jwt` before the other in your `requirements.txt`:

```
boxsdk[jwt]
boxsdk
```

This way, pip will ignore the latter and install as desired.

BUT the correct way to do this is to just throw away the other, making `boxsdk[jwt]` the only thing in your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thanks @iBug. Do you know of any documentation which specifies the behavior of "silently ignores duplicated package specification"?

Comment: @David Maybe [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/993)?

Comment: Ah so that's where the behaviour came in. It's definitely not documented though. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#pip-install I've submitted an issue asking for improvement in their docs and output https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6239 Thanks!