# How are the `extra` flags in pip METADATA Requires-Dist used?

Tags: python, pip

Note:  this isn't a *how to package* question, but rather, once the METADATA has been configured with Requires-Dist extra flags, how are they used at `pip install` time?

#### These 2 dependencies are pretty clear (but do not involve `extra`):

**./loguru-0.3.2.dist-info/METADATA**:

```
Requires-Dist: win32-setctime (>=1.0.0) ; sys_platform == "win32"
```

If you're on win32, `pip install loguru` will pull in `win32-setctime` from pypi.

**./pluggy-0.13.0.dist-info/METADATA**:

```
Requires-Dist: importlib-metadata (>=0.12) ; python_version < "3.8"
```

And here we need `importlib-metadata` if we are on Python 3.7 and earlier.

#### But what about Require-dist that only specify an `extra`?

**SQLAlchemy-1.3.15.dist-info/METADATA**:

```
Requires-Dist: cx-oracle ; extra == 'oracle'
Requires-Dist: pyodbc ; extra == 'mssql_pyodbc'
```

Now, I can understand the *intent* here as well: if you plan on using `Oracle`, SQLAlchemy will at some point need `cx-oracle` from pypi.  Same reasoning with MS SQLServer and `pyodbc`.

However, how exactly are these installs triggered?  I would be extremely unhappy if an SQLAlchemy install automatically pulled in the prereqs for SQL Server and Oracle.  And in fact, I remember installing them separetely, as I should.

Ditto here:

**./loguru-0.3.2.dist-info/METADATA**:

```
Requires-Dist: black (>=19.3b0) ; (python_version >= "3.6") and extra == 'dev'
```

If I plan to develop and I am on 3.6 and above, pull in `black` too.  How do I indicate *intent to develop* via that `extra` at pip install time?

### How does `extra` work in practice?

Is there a `pip install` extra flag?

I see this question: [Specify extras_require with pip install -e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239152/specify-extras-require-with-pip-install-e), but it doesn't really look like I what I expect.  The `-e` flag is for editable installs, so whatever extras also end up there are probably not what I am curious about.

And searching `pip install --help` for extras doesn't look all that promising:
                                  is used.

```
  --use-pep517                Use PEP 517 for building source distributions
                              (use --no-use-pep517 to force legacy behaviour).
  --install-option <options>  Extra arguments to be supplied to the setup.py
--
                              options to setup.py install. If you are using an
                              option with a directory path, be sure to use
                              absolute path.
  --global-option <options>   Extra global options to be supplied to the
--
                              repository compliant with PEP 503 (the simple
                              repository API) or a local directory laid out in
                              the same format.
  --extra-index-url <url>     Extra URLs of package indexes to use in addition
```

Finally, [PEP345](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#requires-dist-multiple-use) doesn't provide much clarity either.

> Requires-Dist (multiple use)
>
> Each entry contains a string naming some other distutils project required by this distribution.
>
> The format of a requirement string is identical to that of a distutils project name (e.g., as found in the Name: field. optionally followed by a version declaration within parentheses.
>
> The distutils project names should correspond to names as found on the Python Package Index [4].
>
> Version declarations must follow the rules described in Version Specifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined in the [core metadata](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#provides-extra-multiple-use) document. This feature allows to bundle extra features with a package. E.g. if a fictive package `foobar` offers some 3d support for rendering, it might provide the `3d` extra feature:

```
Provides-Extra: 3d
Requires-Dist: graphics3d; extra == '3d'
```

The extra feature can be installed with:

```sh
pip install foobar[3d]
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found it a bit later, when I found a question coming in from the other end: [What do square brackets mean in pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775346/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-pip-install), i.e. from someone asking about a particular example of pip's command line use.

#### reminder: SQLAlchemy's partial extra contents:

```
Requires-Dist: cx-oracle ; extra == 'oracle'
Requires-Dist: pyodbc ; extra == 'mssql_pyodbc'
```

You put one or more comma separated extra identifiers, i.e. the `oracle` or `mssql_pyodbc` in my example above, in square brackets.

i.e. `pip install <somepackage>[<extrafeature1>,<extrafeature2>]`

Let's try it out using a brand new virtualenv each time.

#### standard: `pip install sqlalchemy`

`pip list`

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.2.3
setuptools 41.2.0
SQLAlchemy 1.3.17
```

#### bring in pyodbc:  `pip install sqlalchemy[mssql_pyodbc]`

`pip list`

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.2.3
pyodbc     4.0.30
setuptools 41.2.0
SQLAlchemy 1.3.17
```

The packaging viewpoint of this is documented in [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies).