# What does pip install ".[full]" do?

Tags: python, pip

I'm relatively new to Python and thought that I had a basic understanding of `pip install`, but I'm stumped with the following:

```
$ pip install ".[full]"
```

I've only seen `pip install ".[full]"` on a couple of occasions, and I'm not sure what this command actually does. The pattern I've seen is that I clone a git repo, I change directories to that project root, and run `pip install ".[full]"` in my activated virtual environment of choice (I'm using conda). I'm guessing it looks for something in the project, but the terminal output doesn't say exactly what file/directory it is reading. Is this reading the ./build directory, or maybe the ./src directory, or some config file?

setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess
import sys

# Required third-party imports, must be specified in pyproject.toml.
import packaging.version
import setuptools


def process_options():
    """
    Determine all runtime options, returning a dictionary of the results.  The
    keys are:
        'rootdir': str
            The root directory of the setup.  Almost certainly the directory
            that this setup.py file is contained in.
        'release': bool
            Is this a release build (True) or a local development build (False)
    """
    options = {}
    options['rootdir'] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    options = _determine_version(options)
    return options


def _determine_version(options):
    """
    Adds the 'short_version', 'version' and 'release' options.

    Read from the VERSION file to discover the version.  This should be a
    single line file containing valid Python package public identifier (see PEP
    440), for example
      4.5.2rc2
      5.0.0
      5.1.1a1
    We do that here rather than in setup.cfg so we can apply the local
    versioning number as well.
    """
    version_filename = os.path.join(options['rootdir'], 'VERSION')
    with open(version_filename, "r") as version_file:
        version_string = version_file.read().strip()
    version = packaging.version.parse(version_string)
    if isinstance(version, packaging.version.LegacyVersion):
        raise ValueError("invalid version: " + version_string)
    options['short_version'] = str(version.public)
    options['release'] = not version.is_devrelease
    if not options['release']:
        # Put the version string into canonical form, if it wasn't already.
        version_string = str(version)
        version_string += "+"
        try:
            git_out = subprocess.run(
                ('git', 'rev-parse', '--verify', '--short=7', 'HEAD'),
                check=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            )
            git_hash = git_out.stdout.decode(sys.stdout.encoding).strip()
            version_string += git_hash or "nogit"
        # CalledProcessError is for if the git command fails for internal
        # reasons (e.g. we're not in a git repository), OSError is for if
        # something goes wrong when trying to run git (e.g. it's not installed,
        # or a permission error).
        except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, OSError):
            version_string += "nogit"
    options['version'] = version_string
    return options


def create_version_py_file(options):
    """
    Generate and write out the file version.py, which is used to produce the
    '__version__' information for the module.  This function will overwrite an
    existing file at that location.
    """
    filename = os.path.join(
        options['rootdir'], 'src', 'qutip_tensorflow', 'version.py',
    )
    content = "\n".join([
        "# This file is automatically generated during package setup.",
        f"short_version = '{options['short_version']}'",
        f"version = '{options['version']}'",
        f"release = {options['release']}",
    ])
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        print(content, file=file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = process_options()
    create_version_py_file(options)
    # Most of the kwargs to setup are defined in setup.cfg; the only ones we
    # keep here are ones that we have done some compile-time processing on.
    setuptools.setup(
        version=options['version'],
    )
```

setup.cfg

```
"""Extensions to the 'distutils' for large or complex distributions"""

from fnmatch import fnmatchcase
import functools
import os
import re

import _distutils_hack.override  # noqa: F401

import distutils.core
from distutils.errors import DistutilsOptionError
from distutils.util import convert_path

from ._deprecation_warning import SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning

import setuptools.version
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from setuptools.dist import Distribution
from setuptools.depends import Require
from . import monkey


__all__ = [
    'setup',
    'Distribution',
    'Command',
    'Extension',
    'Require',
    'SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning',
    'find_packages',
    'find_namespace_packages',
]

__version__ = setuptools.version.__version__

bootstrap_install_from = None


class PackageFinder:
    """
    Generate a list of all Python packages found within a directory
    """

    @classmethod
    def find(cls, where='.', exclude=(), include=('*',)):
        """Return a list all Python packages found within directory 'where'

        'where' is the root directory which will be searched for packages.  It
        should be supplied as a "cross-platform" (i.e. URL-style) path; it will
        be converted to the appropriate local path syntax.

        'exclude' is a sequence of package names to exclude; '*' can be used
        as a wildcard in the names, such that 'foo.*' will exclude all
        subpackages of 'foo' (but not 'foo' itself).

        'include' is a sequence of package names to include.  If it's
        specified, only the named packages will be included.  If it's not
        specified, all found packages will be included.  'include' can contain
        shell style wildcard patterns just like 'exclude'.
        """

        return list(
            cls._find_packages_iter(
                convert_path(where),
                cls._build_filter('ez_setup', '*__pycache__', *exclude),
                cls._build_filter(*include),
            )
        )

    @classmethod
    def _find_packages_iter(cls, where, exclude, include):
        """
        All the packages found in 'where' that pass the 'include' filter, but
        not the 'exclude' filter.
        """
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(where, followlinks=True):
            # Copy dirs to iterate over it, then empty dirs.
            all_dirs = dirs[:]
            dirs[:] = []

            for dir in all_dirs:
                full_path = os.path.join(root, dir)
                rel_path = os.path.relpath(full_path, where)
                package = rel_path.replace(os.path.sep, '.')

                # Skip directory trees that are not valid packages
                if '.' in dir or not cls._looks_like_package(full_path):
                    continue

                # Should this package be included?
                if include(package) and not exclude(package):
                    yield package

                # Keep searching subdirectories, as there may be more packages
                # down there, even if the parent was excluded.
                dirs.append(dir)

    @staticmethod
    def _looks_like_package(path):
        """Does a directory look like a package?"""
        return os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, '__init__.py'))

    @staticmethod
    def _build_filter(*patterns):
        """
        Given a list of patterns, return a callable that will be true only if
        the input matches at least one of the patterns.
        """
        return lambda name: any(fnmatchcase(name, pat=pat) for pat in patterns)


class PEP420PackageFinder(PackageFinder):
    @staticmethod
    def _looks_like_package(path):
        return True


find_packages = PackageFinder.find
find_namespace_packages = PEP420PackageFinder.find


def _install_setup_requires(attrs):
    # Note: do not use `setuptools.Distribution` directly, as
    # our PEP 517 backend patch `distutils.core.Distribution`.
    class MinimalDistribution(distutils.core.Distribution):
        """
        A minimal version of a distribution for supporting the
        fetch_build_eggs interface.
        """

        def __init__(self, attrs):
            _incl = 'dependency_links', 'setup_requires'
            filtered = {k: attrs[k] for k in set(_incl) & set(attrs)}
            distutils.core.Distribution.__init__(self, filtered)

        def finalize_options(self):
            """
            Disable finalize_options to avoid building the working set.
            Ref #2158.
            """

    dist = MinimalDistribution(attrs)

    # Honor setup.cfg's options.
    dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
    if dist.setup_requires:
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)


def setup(**attrs):
    # Make sure we have any requirements needed to interpret 'attrs'.
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)


setup.__doc__ = distutils.core.setup.__doc__


_Command = monkey.get_unpatched(distutils.core.Command)


class Command(_Command):
    __doc__ = _Command.__doc__

    command_consumes_arguments = False

    def __init__(self, dist, **kw):
        """
        Construct the command for dist, updating
        vars(self) with any keyword parameters.
        """
        _Command.__init__(self, dist)
        vars(self).update(kw)

    def _ensure_stringlike(self, option, what, default=None):
        val = getattr(self, option)
        if val is None:
            setattr(self, option, default)
            return default
        elif not isinstance(val, str):
            raise DistutilsOptionError(
                "'%s' must be a %s (got `%s`)" % (option, what, val)
            )
        return val

    def ensure_string_list(self, option):
        r"""Ensure that 'option' is a list of strings.  If 'option' is
        currently a string, we split it either on /,\s*/ or /\s+/, so
        "foo bar baz", "foo,bar,baz", and "foo,   bar baz" all become
        ["foo", "bar", "baz"].
        """
        val = getattr(self, option)
        if val is None:
            return
        elif isinstance(val, str):
            setattr(self, option, re.split(r',\s*|\s+', val))
        else:
            if isinstance(val, list):
                ok = all(isinstance(v, str) for v in val)
            else:
                ok = False
            if not ok:
                raise DistutilsOptionError(
                    "'%s' must be a list of strings (got %r)" % (option, val)
                )

    def reinitialize_command(self, command, reinit_subcommands=0, **kw):
        cmd = _Command.reinitialize_command(self, command, reinit_subcommands)
        vars(cmd).update(kw)
        return cmd


def _find_all_simple(path):
    """
    Find all files under 'path'
    """
    results = (
        os.path.join(base, file)
        for base, dirs, files in os.walk(path, followlinks=True)
        for file in files
    )
    return filter(os.path.isfile, results)


def findall(dir=os.curdir):
    """
    Find all files under 'dir' and return the list of full filenames.
    Unless dir is '.', return full filenames with dir prepended.
    """
    files = _find_all_simple(dir)
    if dir == os.curdir:
        make_rel = functools.partial(os.path.relpath, start=dir)
        files = map(make_rel, files)
    return list(files)


class sic(str):
    """Treat this string as-is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)"""


# Apply monkey patches
monkey.patch_all()
```

Comment: It'd be better if you could link to a specific example where this is used. Run it outside of a project, and it says `Directory '.[full]' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.`, which answers your question

Comment: `[...]` installs extras, and `.` is the current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your current folder `.`, there is probably a file `setup.py`. In this file you have some extra options. One of them is `full` that probably contains the full dependencies for the current package.

So the command, try to install the package in the current folder and all its dependencies. `full` is just a convenient name, it doesn't mean nothing special for `pip` (or `setup.py`)

A better explanation is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775346/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-pip-install)

Comment: Accepted the answer since it taught me somthing about pip. However, I didn't see "full" in the setup.py. I updated the question to show the code

Comment: What is the package you want to install?

Comment: At a high leve, I want to collect benchmarks by running this file located at ./benchmarks/benchmarks.py
And the readme says to follow these directions here https://github.com/qutip/qutip-tensorflow#benchmarks
This mostly works as expected, but I do not understand what pip is actually doing here

Comment: Take a look to [`setup.cfg`](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-tensorflow/blob/74057b452608b2b6b2cd434bf7664286f18b5f57/setup.cfg#L47-L49) used by `setup.py` for install all depencies for targets `tests` and `benchmarks`.